# contact.php does not send email fields

Tags: php, html, email

My server receives emails but none of the fields are shown.

All fields are empty in the email? Do you have any suggestions? I have tried everything that I know but no results. Form fields does not pass to the php

```
<?php
    // variables start
    $name = "";
    $email = "";
    $message = "";
    
    $name =  trim($_POST['contactNameField']);
    $email =  trim($_POST['contactEmailField']);
    $message =  trim($_POST['contactMessageTextarea']);
    // variables end
    
    // email address starts
    $emailAddress = 'mail@domain.com';
    // email address ends
    
    $subject = "Message From: $name";   
    $message = "<strong>From:</strong> $name <br/><br/> <strong>Message:</strong> $message";
    
    $headers .= 'From: '. $name . '<' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
    
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    
    //send email function starts
    mail($emailAddress, $subject, $message, $headers);
    //send email function ends
?>
```

for this form

```
<form action="php/contact.php" method="post" class="contactForm" id="contactForm">
                    
<div class="form-field form-name">
    <label  class="contactNameField color-theme" >Name:<span>(required)</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="contactNameField"   id="contactNameField" />
</div>
<div class="form-field form-email">
    <label  class="contactEmailField color-theme" >Email:<span>(required)</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="contactEmailField"  id="contactEmailField" />
</div>
<div class="form-field form-text">
    <label  class="contactMessageTextarea color-theme" >Message:<span>(required)</span></label>
    <textarea name="contactMessageTextarea"  id="contactMessageTextarea"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-button">
    <input type="submit" class="btn bg-highlight text-uppercase font-900 btn-m btn-full rounded-sm  shadow-xl contactSubmitButton" value="Gönder"  />
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: First of all you don't need to declare variable with empty value ,you can use directly with the value `$_POST`, for see if all values is receive try to use `print_r($_POST)` and see if actually print your value.

Comment: Are you submitting the form in the old fashioned way, or are you using any js/ajax?

Comment: `Form fields does not pass to the php`...how do you know this exactly? You didn't give any specific results of your debugging.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the old fashioned way.  We do, however, Need Debugging Details.

Comment: Thank you all but sorry I dont know how to debug. I tried some with chrome developer tools and it seems to work fine but I receive empty emails when I submit the form. Email arrives but not the content.

Comment: Debugging is a basic skill which every programmer needs to start learning almost as soon as they write their first program. I am continually astonished when I look at questions on this site that people attempt to write reasonably complex programs seemingly without having understood (or apparently even attempted to find out) anything about how they might go about testing them or detecting errors in them.

Comment: http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/ has a simple guide to debugging with PHP.

Comment: P.S. Chrome dev tools is also useful for debugging any Javascript you may have on your page, and also for monitoring your HTTP requests in the Network tool. When you looked in the dev tools, did you watch the form being submitted, and look inside the request to see whether the data you've submitted in the form is actually being sent in the request?

Comment: Also, a bit of context for us please... is this HTML you've shown also part of "contact.php", or is it in a separate file?

Comment: Also, read https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/ and make sure you've enabled errors and warnings in PHP. As per your code, the first `$headers .= ...` line will be generating a warning because $headers doesn't already exist, so there's nothing to append to. Change that first one to `$headers = ...`. Apart from that, if the form fields are correctly filled in and sent, then the $message variable should contain what's needed - demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c8fb849adbda156168644bb0bc71b58ca2399b8c